# .net membership unsuspend account

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using .net membership to manage my user roles. Currently users are suspended after a long period of inactivity. Is there a membership api to unsuspend the user?

Comment: I don't believe the ASP.NET membership provider has any methods around user suspension / unsuspension. This sounds like custom code that wraps the membership provider.

Comment: Yeah, there is no "suspension" with ASP.NET's default membership provider.  The closest thing is like locking out users after a certain number of failed password attempts.  If you could post some of the code, we'd be able to tell you if you're working with the default membership provider, or a custom one.

Comment: I am sorry. It is actually custom code wrapping around the membership class, which I failed to realize earlier. =(

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'suspension' as such in the Membership Provider; however, there are two properties that will affect the ability of a user to login to the system:

In the **[MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx)** class, let's look at:

**[MembershipUser.IsLockedOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.islockedout.aspx)**:  This property indicates that a user has been locked out of the system by trying to log in with the incorrect password more than the allowed number of times.   The web.config would have that number.

Notice that you **cannot** explicitly lockout a user programmatically.  Only a user herself can get locked out by trying incorrect passwords for her account.

**[MembershipUser.IsApproved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isapproved.aspx)**: You can approve or disapprove a user and that property will define whether a user can be authenticated or not.  This is probably the equivalent to a Suspended user.  You simply set the `MembershipUser.IsApproved` to false and update the user with the `MembershipProvider.UpdateUser(MembershipUser)` method.  Conversely, you would set the property `IsApproved` to true if you want to allow the user to log in again.

Hopefully, this will clarify the capabilities of the Membership provider, but it is strange to see that a user has been 'suspended' from the system due to inactivity.  Are you sure it is not one of the two options discussed above?

Answer (score 0):

If suspend and unsuspend here mean lock/unlock you can try:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("name");
user.UnlockUser();
```